# Change window.location.href upon dismissal of modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, octobercms

Following OctoberCMS guidelines I need to redirect users when they attempt to reach a certain path (ex: www.foo.com/bar) to the home page with php variables (ex: www.foo.com/?bar=1) and have a modal open if the variable is found.

I've created bar.htm which redirects with the proper variable:

```
title = "bar"
url = "/bar"
layout = "default"
meta_title = ""
meta_description = ""
is_hidden = 0
==
<?php
function onStart() {
  header('Location:/?bar=1');
}
?>
==
```

and then in my JS (with #submitBtn being the button on the modal to send the form)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('1') > -1) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
        window.location.href='/';
    })
  } 
});
```

So this is not working, it is just showing the modal in a constant loop and never moving to the success modal or changing the href. This form is working properly in all other situations, so I do not believe the issue lies there.

Shortened example modal code:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var newForm = $('#newFakeForm');
    var config = {
      submitBtn: $('#submitBtn'),
      contactModal: $('#myModal'),
      successModal: $('#successModal'),
    };

    initContactForm(newFakeForm, config);

    });
```

and my HTML button to dismiss the modal:

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What if you do the redirect on JS?
Just listen for the hidden.bs.modal event and do the redirect there.